# `[.factor` raises NextMethod error when qualified by base::

Tags: r, oop

Please explain why the following errors do/don't occur:

```
ff = factor(1:3)
`[.factor`(ff) # okay
base::`[.factor`(ff)  # Error in NextMethod("[") : 'NextMethod' called from an anonymous function
f = `[.factor`; f(ff) # Error in NextMethod("[") : wrong value for .Method
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a surprisingly subtle and complex question.

The reason why `` base::`[.factor`(ff) `` doesn't work and `` `[.factor`(ff)` `` does even though both pieces of code literally invoke *the same function* is because of the unusual way in `NextMethod` works. The TL;DR is that `` `[.factor` `` is s *symbol*, but `` base::`[.factor` ``  is a *call*.

When you invoke `NextMethod`, the [underlying C code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/objects.c#L586C11-L586C29) works out what *context* it was called in, and will throw an error if any of several conditions aren't met.

One of these conditions is that the function in which `NextMethod` resides has to have been called directly - in technical terms, the first node in the call has to be a *symbol*, not an expression. If you try to get the function via a call, `NextMethod` will detect that and give you the "anonymous function" error.

`NextMethod` also checks that the name of the function is consistent with the generic being used, and if there is a mismatch, we get the "wrong value for `.Method`" error

We can demonstrate identical behaviour with a simple example. We have an object of class "foo":

```r
foo <- structure(1:3, class = c("foo"))

foo
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "foo"
```

We want to be able to subset a "foo" so that any subset of a "foo" is still of class "foo", but otherwise we want the exact same subsetting rules as a numeric vector. This is where `NextMethod` comes in:

```r
`[.foo` <- function(obj, ind) {
  y <- NextMethod("[")
  class(y) <- "foo"
  y
}


foo[2]
#> [1] 2
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "foo"
```

This works as expected, and so does calling it directly:

```r
`[.foo`(foo, 2)
#> [1] 2
```

**But**, if we try to call the function *indirectly*, say via `get`, then `NextMethod` throws the error because `get("[.foo")` is a *call*, not a symbol.

```r
get("[.foo")(foo, 2)
#> Error in NextMethod("[") : 'NextMethod' called from an anonymous function
```

Even wrapping the call in parentheses or curly brackets is enough to generate the error (because these brackets are actually calls too)

```r
(`[.foo`)(foo, 2)
#> Error in NextMethod("[") : 'NextMethod' called from an anonymous function

{`[.foo`}(foo, 2)
#> Error in NextMethod("[") : 'NextMethod' called from an anonymous function
```

If we try to rename the function, we get the same error you did with trying to rename `[.factor`:

```r
f <- `[.foo`

f(foo, 2)
#> Error in NextMethod("[") : wrong value for .Method
```

Now `f` is at least a *symbol*, but it is the *wrong* symbol (`f` is not `[`)

The final piece of the puzzle is why `` base::`[.factor` `` isn't a symbol. It's because in R the namespace symbol `::` is actually a *call*, so `` base::`[.factor` `` is actually parsed as `` `::`(base, `[.factor`) ``

```r
class(quote(base::`[.factor`))
#> [1] "call"
```

Whereas, without the namespace identifier, what we have is a *symbol* (a.k.a. "name")

```r
class(quote(`[.factor`))
#> [1] "name"
```